# Where to find the total list of checks of Azsk ARM template checker

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-rm-template

I was wondering if I could somehow could find a list of all the checks that the AZ sk ARM template checker is checking before giving green light.
I want to make a universe file to use in the  'skip controls from file' so that i can reuse the same file with the common checks AZ sk ARM template checker is failing but are for the most of my projects not a security problem.

Thanks !!!

Comment: why dont you look it up yourself in the repo?

Comment: I am sorry to ask ( I am very new to azure) but which repo do you mean .

Comment: the tool you are using? https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs

Comment: It seems that I can't find a list of the most common low severity list , of a list with all the checks AZ sk is checking.

Comment: I hoped that someone tried the AZ sk ARM template checker in full where the check will check every possible check possible (failed , skipped or passed doesn't matter). so that i can use that amount of resource checks or that specific csv file to reuse it in my little project to make an uniform csv to re-use again and again.
The closest i got to a list of all checks is a list of all resource types : https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/blob/master/02-Secure-Development/Readme.md#what-azure-resource-types-that-can-be-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'll probably convert this to an answer because of the inability of the OP to find the answer with google and some common sense

https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit/blob/master/src/AzSK/ARMCheckerLib/controls.gen.json

Comment: google i? I cant possible have time to maintain consistency of links in thousands of the answers I've given. quick look through the repo shows this might be the answer now: https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit/blob/master/src/AzSK.AzureDevOps/Framework/Configurations/SVT/ControlSettings.json